# Django model: Filtering by user, always

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I achieve the following....

Every time the points object is displayed in a template it must always be filtered by the current user. So, within the model I tried the code below.

Is this possible? how can I achieve the above?

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


POINTS_PENDING, POINTS_ADDED, POINTS_DEDUCTED, ORDER_PROCESSING = range(4)
STATUS_OPTIONS = (
    (POINTS_PENDING, ('Pending')),
    (POINTS_ADDED, ('Added')),
    (POINTS_DEDUCTED, ('Deducted')),
    (ORDER_PROCESSING, ('Processing')),
    )


class PointsManager(models.Manager):

    def points_list(self,User):
        list = Points.objects.filter(points_user=User).exclude(status=ORDER_PROCESSING)
        return list


class Points (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("Points"), default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(("Created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=("Updated at"), auto_now=True)

    objects = PointsManager()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could ensure that your views have a user by using

[`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator

then you could could query for points by user in your view

`user_points = Points.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

or using the reverse [FK lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

`request.user.points_set.all()`

Comment: Not very clever. I think the answer was if this can be done Always - Automatically, in one centralized place. Your solution has disadvantages: 1) what if the filter condition is more complex? 2) How to make this working inside admin pages? 3) if you repeat this in 20 views are you sure that you remember add id in the 21st view too? - so I haven't found many help here..

Comment: I kind of agree with mirek. You do offer some solutions but applying this condition on the model rather than on request seems much more sensible to me. That kind of thing is possible with a framework such as Spring and I hope the find the same stuff in Django.

Comment: To people that want an inversion of control where the model is aware about the current request / user, that's generally against the design principles of Django itself. See this particular answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219902/how-to-safely-access-request-object-in-django-models/52220370#52220370

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a mixin:

```
class OwnershipPermissionMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = args[0] if args else kwargs.get('request') or self.request
        query = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return query.filter(user=request.user)
```

And make the views (admin or classic) inherits from it. Then each time the queryset is evaluated, it will filter for owned objects only.