# Filter reservations created by logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to display all the reservations created by the currently logged-in user.

[Django model: Filtering by user, always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026750/django-model-filtering-by-user-always)

[Documentation: Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

are some of the links I checked but still haven't been able to solve the problem.

Model.py

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pickup_date = models.DateField()
    pickup_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    drop_date = models.DateField()
    drop_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    drop_location = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=250, choices=LOCATIONS_CHOICES)
    reserved_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
class ReservationList(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Reservation
    context_object_name = 'reservations'
    queryset= Reservation.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^reservations/$', ReservationList.as_view(), name='reservations_list'),
```

I get this error when I run the server

```
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'user'
```

How do I display only reservations created by the currently logged in user. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `queryset= Reservation.objects.filter(user=request.user)` see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know what exactly I am supposed to look out for over there. what's the catch please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `get_queryset` method of ListView, you can't do it by setting a static property (`queryset`) on the class. Here's how to do it:

```
class ReservationListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Reservation
    context_object_name = 'reservations'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Reservation.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```