# How to get current account id in django models.py

Tags: python, django

1. I want to get the id of the current account in django models.py. I know I can get the user object of the current account by adding 'request.user'. However, the function I am using requires the use of the self argument to be used in the condition, so 'request' cannot be used together. Please help.

[models.py]

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    kind = models.CharField(choices=KIND_CHOICES, max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)


    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('leave:leave_edit', args=(self.id,))

        if self.kind == 'Annual' and self.user.id == self.user_id:
            return f'<div class="Annual-title"><a href="{url}" style="color:black;"> {self.name} </a></div>'
        elif self.kind == 'Annual' and self.user.id != self.user_id:
            return f'<div class="Annual-title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leave_{self.id}"> {self.name} </div>'
```

---

2. Does the method below work normally?

[models.py]

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    kind = models.CharField(choices=KIND_CHOICES, max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def user_id(request):      +++ add
        return request.user

   @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('leave:leave_edit', args=(self.id,))

        if self.kind == 'Annual' and self.user.id == Leave.user_id:
            return f'<div class="Annual-title"><a href="{url}" style="color:black;"> {self.name} </a></div>'
        elif self.kind == 'Annual' and self.user.id != Leave.user_id:
            return f'<div class="Annual-title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leave_{self.id}"> {self.name} </div>'
```

Comment: Have already asked it here check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219902/how-to-safely-access-request-object-in-django-models

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why you are doing it in `models.py` file.

You can get current account id in your `views.py`.

```
def yourfunction(request):
    ....
    user = request.user
    user_id = user.id
    ....
```